# How docker containers are shared with host directories

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, openfaas

When creating a function on OpenFaaS, OpenFaaS automatically creates a container. How can I enable this container to share directories with the host machine?

I would like to access a specific file on the host machine from within the function code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.